# how to pass where clause as a parameter into $this->model->getRows() in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I copy and pasts this code from another source to my laravel project and it works well to retrieve all values of a table.
Now I would like to pass `"where is_active=1"` as a parameter `to $this->model->getRows();`

How can I do this? Below is my code:

```
  $params = array(
            'page'      => $page ,
            'limit'     => (!is_null($request->input('rows')) ? filter_var($request->input('rows'),FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : static::$per_page ) ,
            'sort'      => $sort ,
            'order'     => $order,
            'params'    => $filter,
            'global'    => (isset($this->access['is_global']) ? $this->access['is_global'] : 0 )
        );
        // Get Query 
        $results = $this->model->getRows( $params );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->model->where('is_active','=',1)->getRows( $params );
```

or

```
$this->model->getRows( $params )->where('is_active','=',1);
```

Comment: i fixed it myself using this code,  $filter = (!is_null($request->input('search')) ? $this->buildSearch() : 'and is_active=1'); here $filter actually sends the search parameters,

Comment: i tried your answer but it didn't work for me!! it throws the error "BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1992: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRows()"